# Can not get a configuration file for GCM (android and ios)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

After click blue-button in this page https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client and error in browser console:

[image]

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passive=true&authuser=0&continue=console.developers.google.com/mobilesdk/bootstrap/wizard/android?authuser%3D0%26hl%3Den%26cnturl%3Ddevelopers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client%26cntlbl%3DContinue%2BAdding%2BGCM%2BSupport%26cntapi%3Dgcm&hl=en does not permit framing.

I tried it in firefox and chrome with the same result.

UPDATE:
I remove project from console and create new. Now developers.google.com/mobile/add works fine. Mysterious behaviour

Comment: Error in chrome http://i.imgur.com/nxf1KT9.png

Comment: Have you used the "send feedback" tool on the previous page?

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. But may be there is another way to get configuration file? I have no time =(

Answer (score 3):

Seems like some temporary issue at Google end. Meanwhile use the below link to do the process:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

You will be asked to give the details like Project Name, package, etc and then it would give you the option to select the services. Select Google Could Messaging service. Finally it would give you an option to download the configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

--> under the API Manager, create a key or use the existing key

--> click the download icon to download the json configuration file.

[image]

**EDIT**

You can check your configuration file with following format:

```
{"project_info":{"project_id":"YOUR_PROJECT_ID","project_number":"YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER","name":"YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"},"client":[{"client_info":{"mobilesdk_app_id":"1:673329586750:android:f36173e948059ccb","client_id":"android:gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart","client_type":1,"android_client_info":{"package_name":"gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"}},"oauth_client":[],"api_key":[],"services":{"analytics_service":{"status":1},"cloud_messaging_service":{"status":1,"apns_config":[]},"appinvite_service":{"status":1,"other_platform_oauth_client":[]},"google_signin_service":{"status":1},"ads_service":{"status":1}}},{"client_info":{"mobilesdk_app_id":"","client_id":"android:com.google.android.gms.samples.appinvite","client_type":1,"android_client_info":{"package_name":"com.google.android.gms.samples.appinvite"}},"oauth_client":[{"client_id":"673329586750-7pl633luu5853v7lq5micimjknmuj527.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_type":1,"android_info":{"package_name":"com.google.android.gms.samples.appinvite","certificate_hash":"E07D385930D0BAA8A2B63322396987885A3B7C22"}}],"api_key":[],"services":{"analytics_service":{"status":1},"cloud_messaging_service":{"status":1,"apns_config":[]},"appinvite_service":{"status":2,"other_platform_oauth_client":[]},"google_signin_service":{"status":1},"ads_service":{"status":1}}},{"client_info":{"mobilesdk_app_id":"1:673329586750:android:27d689d63f1b7a06","client_id":"android:com.google.samples.quickstart.signin","client_type":1,"android_client_info":{"package_name":"com.google.samples.quickstart.signin"}},"oauth_client":[{"client_id":"673329586750-bepted85l74k08c8nap26gm4j253gvo6.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_type":1,"android_info":{"package_name":"com.google.samples.quickstart.signin","certificate_hash":"E07D385930D0BAA8A2B63322396987885A3B7C22"}}],"api_key":[],"services":{"analytics_service":{"status":1},"cloud_messaging_service":{"status":1,"apns_config":[]},"appinvite_service":{"status":1,"other_platform_oauth_client":[]},"google_signin_service":{"status":2},"ads_service":{"status":1}}}],"client_info":[],"ARTIFACT_VERSION":"1"}
```

**EDIT**

In `developer console`: Remove project and create new project can resolve connection problem.

Comment: With this config.json build process returns
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing project_info object

Comment: Thanks. But I found another solution. See in the first post.

Comment: So it was connect console problem, i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this same problem
I think this may be because I wasn't signed in fully. I've just gone to the google developers console link (https://console.developers.google.com/project) provided by bjiang and it prompted me to log in, so I did. After this I reloaded the original page for the configuration file and it loaded. I'm guessing I was logged in via a long term key that didn't have the correct permissions.